# refactoring Rxjs observables using functions that make semantic sense and reduce mess

Tags: angular, rxjs, refactoring

I want to refactor a chain of observables so that thay make semantic sence, my code looks close to this.

```
//Ajax call that gets the users data
this.getUser
  .pipe(
    flatmap((user)=>{
       //Stuff that gets the user's picture
    }),
    flatmap((picture)=>{
       //Stuff that saves the user's picture
    }),
  )
```

All that does not make semantic sense, I need to read the code to know what it's doing, I would like to refactor it to get something that looks somewhat like this.

```
this.getUser
  .pipe(
    getPicture(),
    savePicture()
  )

function getPicture(user){
  //Stuff that gets the user's picture
  return picture
}


function savePicture(picture){
  //Stuff that saves the user's picture
}
```

How can I refactor the original code to have a cleaner and more readable structure?

Comment: This is well documented here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily

Comment: that's some funny sintax over there.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getUser.pipe(getPicture, savePicture);

export function getPicture(user$: Observable<user>) =>
    (user$) => user$.pipe(flatmap((user) => {
        //Stuff that gets the user's picture
    });


export function savePicture(picture$: Observable<Picture>) =>
    (picture$) => picture$.pipe(flatmap((picture) => {
        //Stuff that saves the user's picture
    });
```